# Mat-sort is not working even though my datasource _sort variable does change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, datasource, mean-stack

In an Angular app I am loading data from a database using

**data.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Post} from '../Post';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getData(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>('http://localhost:80/Findall');
}

getCategories() {
    return this.categories;
}

findCaldera(index: string) {
    console.log('find: ' + index);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:80/Find/' + index);
}

updateCaldera(index: string, data) {
    console.log('find: ' + index);
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:80/Update/' + index, data);
}

addPost(data) {
    console.log('add: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    return this.http.post<Post>('http://localhost:80/Add', data);
}

deletePost(index: string) {
    console.log('delete: ' + index);
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:80/Delete/' + index,     {responseType:'text'});
}
}
```

This therefore returns an observable to  my dashboard where the data is displayed

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data/data.service';
import {Post} from '../Post';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthService} from '../auth.service';

import {PostDialogComponent} from '../post-dialog/post-dialog.component';
import {EditComponent} from '../edit/edit.component';
import {MatDialog, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, public auth: AuthService, public dialog: MatDialog) {
  }
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  displayedColumns = ['Borrower1','_id', 'edit','delete'];
  dataSource: PostDataSource |null;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataSource = new PostDataSource(this.dataService, this.sort);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(()=>{console.log(this.dataSource)});
  }


  deletePost(id) {
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.dataService.deletePost(id).subscribe(()=>{
        this.dataSource = new PostDataSource(this.dataService, this.sort);
      }); 
    } else {
      alert('Login in Before');
    }
  }

  editDialog(id): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditComponent, {
      width: '100%',
      data: id,

    });
    dialogRef.componentInstance.event.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result.data)
      this.dataSource = new PostDataSource(this.dataService, this.sort);
    });
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PostDialogComponent, {
      width: '100%',
      data: 'Add Post'
    });
    dialogRef.componentInstance.event.subscribe((result) => {
      console.log(result.data)
      this.dataService.addPost(result.data).subscribe(()=>{
        this.dataSource = new PostDataSource(this.dataService, this.sort);
      });
    });
  }
}



export class PostDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private _sort: MatSort) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Post[]> {
    console.log("hi1")
    return this.dataService.getData();
  }

  disconnect() {
  }
}
```

When i click on the sort arrow on the html page an event is emitted as i can see from `this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(()=>{console.log(this.dataSource)});`

within the dataSource the `_sort` property changes to reflect the changes i make by click on the sort arrow in the view i.e after 1 click the `dataSource._sort.order = "asc"` and then after another click `dataSource._sort.order = "desc"`. However the data in the table does not change. There are many example that use MatTableDataSource but I have read that it isn't good practice to use this when using http to get my data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use MatSort with asynchronous data you should listen the sort changes and for every one make a call to get the sorted data.

Here is an example. I hope this help.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xugwa)

**UPDATED ANSWER**

If you use DataSource then your data wont be sorted automatically, you have to listen sort changes. One way of doing it could be the following

```js
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

export class PostDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private _sort: MatSort) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return combineLatest(
      this.dataService.getData(),
      this.sort.sortChange.pipe(startWith(null)),
      (data, sort) => {
        return this.sortData(data, sort);
      }
    )
  }

  disconnect() {
  }

  sordData(data, sort) {
     // Sort data
     return this.data;
  }
}
```

Notice sortChange has startWith. That is because [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) require all observable to emit at least once

Comment: you are making a async call every time you want to sort static data ..?

Comment: As far as I meant, yes. Thats the way of doing it if you sort at server side or if you have pagination. But reading the code again it seems he fetch all the data at once so sorting at client side would be a better option. I wil update the answer.